# atNavButton change button text to icon in meteor-useraccounts

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I've just started playing with the Meteor framework and am creating a sign in/register form based upon these [boilerplaters](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#button-text).

I want to change the text on the `navSignIn` button from text to an icon. I tried:

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
    texts: {
        navSignIn: "fa fa-rocket"
    }
});
```

This however does not display an icon and I'm unsure where else to change it in the configure file. Where could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't replace text with icons in [`meteor-useraccounts`](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core) at the moment (see [GitHub issue #233](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/issues/233)).

However, you could create your custom template and use the [`aldeed:template-extension`](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/template-extension) package to replace the corresponding template:

1. Run `meteor add aldeed:template-extension`.
2. Create the following template:

---

```
<template name="atNavButtonFa">
    <button type="button" id="at-nav-button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i></button>
</template>
```

3. Add the following code to replace the `atNavButton` template:

---

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.atNavButtonFa.replaces("atNavButton");
}
```